# Aggregate Sorting

Tags: python, pandas

```
data2 = data[data["Deaths"]>0]
data2= data2.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=False)
data2.groupby(['CCAA']).agg({'Date': [np.min]})
```

With this code I am finding the date of the first death for every region. The problem is I need to sort them by date and not alphabetically like it is. Why is my sorting not working?

```html
 Date
amin
CCAA 
Andalucía 2020-03-13
Aragón         2020-03-08
Asturias 2020-03-11
Baleares 2020-03-11
C. Valenciana 2020-03-08
Canarias 2020-03-13
Cantabria 2020-03-17
Castilla La     2020-03-11
Castilla y León 2020-03-13
Cataluña 2020-03-08
Ceuta         2020-03-27
Extremadura 2020-03-10
Galicia         2020-03-14
La Rioja        2020-03-09
Madrid         2020-03-08
Melilla         2020-03-25
Murcia         2020-03-20
Navarra         2020-03-15
País Vasco 2020-03-08
```

Comment: the date is in datetime format right?

Comment: Yes its in datetime format

Comment: @Cpython try to `sort_values` after the `agg` not before, especially because you jus want the mean of date per group, sorting before is not really necessary.See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/groupby.html#groupby-sorting) "By default the group keys are sorted during the groupby operation. You may however pass sort=False for potential speedups"

Comment: Nothing happens when I do it after. I don't even get the table alphabetically.

Comment: does `datos2.groupby(['CCAA']).agg({'Date': 'min'}).sort_values()` work for your?

Comment: This worked thanks Quang!

Answer (score 0):

From a similar dataset:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datadista/datasets/master/COVID%2019/ccaa_covid19_casos_long.csv')

df = df[df['total']>0]
df= df.sort_values(by = 'fecha', ascending  = True)
df = df[['CCAA', 'fecha']].groupby(['CCAA']).first()
df = df.sort_values(by = 'fecha')
df

                      fecha
CCAA    
Andalucía        2020-02-27
Madrid           2020-02-27
Canarias         2020-02-27
C. Valenciana    2020-02-27
Cataluña         2020-02-27
...
La Rioja         2020-03-02
Galicia          2020-03-04
Murcia           2020-03-08
Melilla          2020-03-13
Ceuta            2020-03-15
```

Comment: Thank you very much !